# Split a large [MLMultiArray] into smaller chunks [[MLMultiArray]]?

Tags: swift, multidimensional-array, coreml

I have a large MLMultiArray of length 15360 values.

Sample:

```
Float32 1 x 15360
[14.78125,-0.6308594,5.609375,13.57812,-1.871094,-19.65625,9.5625,8.640625,-2.728516,3.654297,-3.189453,-1.740234...]
```

Is there a way I can convert this huge array into 120 small MLMultiArrays with 128 elements each without changing the sequence of this array and in the most efficient way possible?

The entire array of 15360 elements is available in this [Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UKwmuO0bRH20-i76Ss-bI_vUn8q1Tcit/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Why do you need to do this? (I ask because you probably don't need to do this.)

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans Thank you so much I should have noticed this sooner. I could have converted the MLMultiArray into Float or Double. This wouldn't have been an issue if I had done it earlier. So early morning I tried converting the MLMultiArray to float value as soon as I received it from MLFeatureValueObservation and It worked. 

thanks for the eye-opener :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```swift
let chunkSize = 2
let shape = yourLargeArray.shape
let chunkedArrays = try? stride(from: 0, to: shape.count, by: chunkSize)
    .map { offset -> MLMultiArray in
        let startIndex = shape.index(shape.startIndex, offsetBy: offset)
        let endIndex = shape.index(startIndex, offsetBy: chunkSize, limitedBy: shape.endIndex) ?? shape.endIndex

        return try MLMultiArray(
            shape: Array(shape[startIndex ..< endIndex]), 
            dataType: yourLargeArray.dataType
        )
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Adrian. I tried it out but I am getting an error stating the following.

Cannot invoke 'stride' with an argument list of type '(from: Int, to: MLMultiArray, by: Int)'

I search through google to find a solution and one of the questions told me to use Swift.stride. I tried that out too but I keep getting the same error.